# Can't import packages that is shown in pip list

Tags: python, pip, scipy, imutils

For some reason, after i install `imutils` package with `pip install imutils`, which I guess has succeeded since it's shown when I run `pip list` but when I import it, it said `Import "imutils" could not be resolved`? The same thing happens to the `scipy` package as well, I can't find a direct answer to this problem, really appreciate if someone can help.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

as i see, you've installed the package **globally** meaning you didn't create a **virtual environement** in `ImageProcessor` folder.

try this

```
PS D:\Homework\AI\Homework\ImageProcessor> py -m venv venv
PS D:\Homework\AI\Homework\ImageProcessor> .\venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) PS D:\Homework\AI\Homework\ImageProcessor> pip list
(venv) PS D:\Homework\AI\Homework\ImageProcessor> pip install imutils scipy
(venv) PS D:\Homework\AI\Homework\ImageProcessor> pip list
```